# How to establish database connection between spring MVC + PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc

Currently am working on Spring MVC and I have included dependency for PostgreSQL but whenever i tried to start connection it fails.
Here is my pom.xml codes

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>sms</groupId>
      <artifactId>system</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>system Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <dependencies>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
        <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>  
       </dependency>  

       <dependency>    
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>    
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>    
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>    
    </dependency>  
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>system</finalName>
      </build>
    </project>
```

This is the codes from -servlet file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xsi:schemaLocation=" 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">  

    <!-- Provide support for component scanning -->  
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint" />  
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <!--Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation -->  
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
</beans>
```

This is the codes from web.xml file

```
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
     "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
    <web-app>
      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
      <servlet>    
        <servlet-name>sms</servlet-name>    
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>      
    </servlet>    
    <servlet-mapping>    
        <servlet-name>sms</servlet-name>    
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
    </servlet-mapping>    
    </web-app>



The configuration of jdbc driver 
[jdbc driver][2]

In the end i get this error
[error][3]
```

i tried to  download the jdbc driver version that matches with my jdk but still i get the same error..
is there something wrong with my approach? How can i solve this?    Any help from you guys will be much appreciated

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEePs.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep3lz.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j8v0.png
```

T**HE ERROR MESSAGE FROM "DETAILS" BUTTON**

> ```
> Could not connect to smsDatabase.
> Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to smsDatabase. (Error: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are
> ```
>
> correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
>       Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       Stack Trace:
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:60)
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:77)
>         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:116)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.Jdbc2Connection.(Jdbc2Connection.java:24)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:369)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:245)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.createConnection(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:87)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionInfoImpl.initializeJDBCConnection(ConnectionInfoImpl.java:705)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionInfoImpl.(ConnectionInfoImpl.java:690)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:38)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.SQMConnectionFactory.createConnection(SQMConnectionFactory.java:45)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:59)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryAdapterProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryAdapterProvider.java:114)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ManagedConnection.createConnection(ManagedConnection.java:163)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.CreateConnectionJob.run(CreateConnectionJob.java:56)
>         at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>       End of Stack Trace
>       )
>       Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
>       Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       Stack Trace:
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:60)
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:77)
>         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:116)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.Jdbc2Connection.(Jdbc2Connection.java:24)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:369)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:245)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.createConnection(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:87)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionInfoImpl.initializeJDBCConnection(ConnectionInfoImpl.java:705)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionInfoImpl.(ConnectionInfoImpl.java:690)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:38)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.SQMConnectionFactory.createConnection(SQMConnectionFactory.java:45)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:59)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryAdapterProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryAdapterProvider.java:114)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ManagedConnection.createConnection(ManagedConnection.java:163)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.CreateConnectionJob.run(CreateConnectionJob.java:56)
>         at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>       End of Stack Trace
>
> ```
> Error creating PostgreSQL JDBC Connection Factory connection to smsDatabase. (Error: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and
> ```
>
> port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP
>   connections.
>       Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       Stack Trace:
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:60)
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:77)
>         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:116)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.Jdbc2Connection.(Jdbc2Connection.java:24)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:369)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:245)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.createConnection(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:87)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ManagedConnection.createConnection(ManagedConnection.java:166)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.CreateConnectionJob.run(CreateConnectionJob.java:56)
>         at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>       End of Stack Trace
>       )
>       Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
>       Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       Stack Trace:
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:60)
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:77)
>         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:116)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.Jdbc2Connection.(Jdbc2Connection.java:24)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:369)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:245)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.createConnection(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:87)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ManagedConnection.createConnection(ManagedConnection.java:166)
>         at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.CreateConnectionJob.run(CreateConnectionJob.java:56)
>         at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55) End of Stack Trace

Comment: The URLs to the screenshots you posted have nothing to do with Spring MVC. You're trying to connect from Eclipse, not from your application using Spring MVC. Clicking the "Details" button would probably tell you more details about what the problem is.

Comment: So how do i connect using Spring MVC?

Comment: I clicked "Details" still i could not figure out the source of problem

Comment: Maybe if you posted the details (as text, not as URLs to images), we could? Regarding conecting to a database using Spring: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc

Comment: in case you want to take a look on the error messages i have edited my question..in the meantime thanks for reply i will take a look on the link posted

Comment: The message says: "Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections". Did you do that? Do you have a PostgreSQL database server running on your machine, on port 1543, and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: All i did was to browse the path for jar file that i downloaded and provide  username, i did not know about hostname and i left the port number 5432 as it was..How can i configure those details?

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to connect to PostgreSQL, but haven't even installed and started PostgreSQL? If so, how could that work? That's like trying to browse a web site that doesn't exist. Or try to phone to your house without any phone line installed in your house. To connect to a database server, there needs to be a database server.

Comment: Am new to spring MVC i tried to google on how to make the connection so far what i get is what I have done so far i thought doing that would complete the whole things required for database ....so it would be  much of a  help if you would tell me about how to do so the right way.....I have the tomcat server 9.0.1 running if that counts

Comment: Again, you need to download, install and configure PostgreSQL on your machine. Or at least, if it's just for development, use a docker container that runs PostgreSQL for you. Using an embedded, or more lightweight databse like H2 would be easier, but you really need to understand the concept of a server that you connect to. If you want to connect to a server, there needs to be a server.